# How can i do the Q filter search based on dictionary and its keys in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose i have this dictionary

```
mydict['number'] = {23,24,25}
mydict['name'] = {"john","mike","kaff"}
mydict['area'] = {"london", "usa", "japan"}
```

I already have the query set `qs`

But i want to have additional filtering based on above `dictionary` something like

`qs.filter (where number __icontains  in 23,24,25)`

and `qs.filter (where name __icontains in john, mike, kaff)` and so on

EDIT:

This is what i have tried but rough

```
query_list = []

for key1 in mydict.iteritems():
  for myval in  mydict[key1]:
    qry = qry + Q(myval__icontains= myval) |
query_list.append(qry)

queryset = Student.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, query_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the argument to `filter` from `Q` objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I have edited my question on what i ahve tried but how can i correct it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
for k, v in mydict:
    qs.filter('%s__icontains' % k=v)
```

Comment: This is AND. `icontains in` means he needs OR.